# Android scale a bitmap to a specific file size

Tags: android, bitmap, resize, image-resizing

Before to say this is a duplicate, please read as I did not find my answer on the other topics. I am trying to resize (if needed) a bitmap to a specific size but this size is in Ko (not height/width).

The problem is the following

1) In my app, the user can select pictures from facebook, gallery or the camera

2) I get all of those as bitmap format and they all came with different width to height ratio and different compression rate.

3) I need to store those pictures on my server so that the user can see them in my app at a later point if he comes back. But I want to save a version of about 200/100Ko for each picture.

4) The problem is that if I resize the bitmap to be the same size say 800*600, and then compress the picture to 50% then some bitmaps (that were compressed) will basically take more space than if I was doing nothing and they will not look as good too as 2 layer of compression will be done.

5) I need to find a way to compress my bitmap only if it needs to be compressed and not increasing his size by doing those manipulations. The documentation on this topic looks much more limited, as every questions asked about resizing a picture to a certain size in width/height but not in terms of space.

If any one has links or recommendations on this, would be very happy to hear from you, thanks

Comment: Can you add some more detail about the images on the device vs. images on the server and the interaction between the app and the server?  Because if you are trying to target a certain encoding size on the server, I would just upload the image and do all that resizing work on the server.  You could even decode and re-encode the image a couple different ways, compare all their sizes and just save the smallest one.

Comment: Please divide into serval quesitions.